# Sublime Text 3 in 4K resolution, text too small, snippet suggestions too large

Tags: sublimetext3, screen-resolution, text-size

I am just learning how to code right now, and I use both my desktop (1080p res) and laptop (4K res). I love sublime text 3, I think it's wonderful, and I use it on my desktop all the time...but when I try using it on my 4K laptop, the text is way too small, and the snippet suggestions are way too big. What I mean by that is when I type `<ti`, it suggests `<title>` but the little suggestion window is all wonky and big and out of focus (I don't know how to explain it).

Things I've tried...

**1)** changing `font-size` in settings. This was only able to increase the size of the font slightly, but made the snippet suggestion problem even worse. Also I ran into another problem... At about `font-size: 19,` the font size stops increasing. So `font-size: 19,` to `font-size: 22` are all the same size, but `font-size: 23,` is all of a sudden HUGE.

**2)** changing my computer's screen resolution to 1080p. This makes things a little better, but all the text is now blurry, it's not crisp anymore. After a couple hours it makes your eyes hurt/tired to look at. Plus it sucks having to switch my computer from 4K to 1080p every time I want to code.

I've searched a whole bunch (on google and here) and it doesn't seem like anyone else is having this issue :(.

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Thank you,

SGBurek

Answer (score 0):

OK, problem solved I think...

So what I was doing previously was that I copied ALL of the default settings into user settings, and just changed the one line of code `font-size:`, but I just tried something different. I tried ONLY putting `font-size` in my user settings and everything worked perfectly...

not sure *why* that happened, but happy that everything is a-okay! :)

SGBurek